# why can't I get the button to form inline?

Tags: html, css

I want the btn next to the string. I can't figure it out even using CSS inline

[image]

```
 <span class="subscribe_button"> <h3>Books</h3> <%= render 'follow_form' %></span>
```

CSS:

```
.subscribe_button {
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: You want books after the button?

Comment: Books before. Thanks everyone for the quick responses im looking into all the answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some invalid HTML here.

A block level element cannot be within an inline one, this is basic HTML knowledge.

What I suggest you do is wrap both elements in a `div` and use float: left;

```
<div class="wrap">

<h3>Books</h3>
<span class="subscribe_button"> unsubscribe</span>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap
{
    width: 300px;
}

.wrap h3, 
.wrap span
{
    float: left;
}

.wrap span
{
    margin-left: 10px/*your value*/;
}
```

I also suggest you go read up on HTML rules, what is allowed where and why they are or are not allowed.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/zJUZs/

Comment: Thanks I'm new to programming. As cowls said other stuff came on the same line because of the float thus I had to also add a <br/>

Answer (score 1):

The `Books` part is (also) a block (due to `<h1>`), so you need to set it to `inline` as well (as shown in the comment of [limelights](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441387/limelights)), otherwise your button will still be pushed to the next line.

Comment: The css selector for that would be `.subscribe_button h3 { display: inline; }` Toy with it here https://tinker.io/b0eeb

Comment: What you're saying make sense however, it doesn't work with this method but the float method works

Comment: The link @limelights provided shows that this method *does work*... But feel free to use any method you like of course!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your CSS

```
.subscribe_button h3 {
    float: left;
}
```

If you float an element it means other elements after it will wrap onto the same line as it (as long as theyre width does not make them too wide).

Answer (score 0):

Span is inline element and h3 is block element. Inline elements should be inside block elements. Have you tried to validate your html code? http://validator.w3.org/

try:
display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with this code:

```
.subscribe_button > * {
  display: inline;
}
```

'>' is a child selector and * matches to all element.

Yo can read more about CSS2 selectors: [CSS2 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
.subscribe_button h3{
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` for both `h3` and `button`